# mime types settings

Tags: json, html, mime-types, mime

I am using Ipage as a web host and I recently figured that an Html document I have
on my server wouldn't work because a json.z file it is using is read by the browser as `"text/html"` instead of `"application/json; charset=UTF-8"` (checked it out in fiddler).

How can I change this? Is it possible in a host like Ipage to set mime types or even view the list to find an extension which will be supported as `"application/json; charset=UTF-8"`?

If not, It's not the first time that Ipage's "simplicity" limits my possibilities, what other hosts are more professional and will enable me to do that?

Comment: did you try using .json as extension?

Comment: Yes. Still read as "text/html".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set mime types on your server edit the ".htaccess" file, here is how:
http://www.htaccess-guide.com/adding-mime-types/

Specificly on ipage there is a ".htaccess editor" which is easily reachable in the control panel and there you can add mime types:
 http://members.ipage.com/controlpanel/htaccess/?m=mimetypes